# Why is this regex replacing the dash character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to better understand regular expressions, but can't seem to understand this.

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.?!\s]/", "", $mystring);
```

I thought that this would not replace dashes, because it would be counted as "through" in the example above.  But every time I run it, the dash is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't provide a sample `$mystring` value, which would be helpful.

As it is written, this regular expression will replace one, and only one, character in `$mystring`. Specifically, your character class includes a carat character (`^`) at the very beginning. In any Perl-compatible regular expression engine (of which PHP is one), this indicates *not these things* (see [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) for more). So your expression is essentially stripping anything that is **not**:

- A lowercase letter between a and z
- An uppercase letter between A and Z
- A digit between 0 and 9
- A period
- A question mark
- An exclamation mark
- A whitespace character

The dash character is **not** one of the above, so it gets matched and replaced.

Your assumption about the "through"-ness of the dashes as you have written it are correct, however. The dash character is one of the 4 special characters in a character class, and it gets used to indicate a range of characters.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation. :)